How to use dynamic task mapping in Airflow with KubernetesPodOperator
It seems like the only way to pull xcom values in a KubernetesPodOperator task is by setting do_xcom_push=True and using a templated xcom_pull, ie "{{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='foo', key='bar') }}".  However, I need to use dynamic task mapping to create a dynamic number of KubernetesPodOperator tasks based on the values generated from the previous task.  I'm using airflow version 2.5.3.
My question is how do I get this to work?
def generate_list(**kwargs):
    # generate list of values
    return [item1, item2, item3, ...]


generate_list_task = PythonOperator(
    task_id='generate_list',
    python_callable=generate_list,
    provide_context=True,
    dag=dag
)

KubernetesPodOperator.partial(
    dag=dag,
    task_id='my_task',
    name='my_name',
    image='my_image',
    image_pull_policy='IfNotPresent',
    do_xcom_push=True,
    is_delete_operator_pod=True,
    in_cluster=True,
    get_logs=True
).expand(
    arguments="{{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='generate_list', key='return_value') }}"
)

But the templated xcom_pull is not resolving in the above code.  It's just expanding the literal template string.  For example:
arguments="{"
arguments="{"
arguments=" "
arguments="t"
arguments="i"
arguments="."
...

Also note, when I don't use dynamic task mapping the template string correctly resolves to the xcom value such as in the below code.
KubernetesPodOperator(
    arguments="{{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='foo', key='return_value') }}",
    ...
)

I've been unsuccessful in finding any working examples or documentation online.

What do you mean the template "is not resolving"? Is it expanding the literal template string, pieces of it? It would be helpful to see what it is displaying now.

@JoshFell Yes, that's correct.  It's exanding the literal template string so that each task instance gets 1 character of it.  See my edit above.  All I want is to be able to do dynamic task mapping from an array stored in xcom
